# Generic Return Types

Tags: java, generics, return-type

Would there be a better way to write this getInput() method instead of checking for every single class that could be passed in?

```
    public Object getInput(String prompt, Class<?> type) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        Scanner scn = new Scanner( System.in );
        String str = scn.nextLine( );
        if(type.equals(Integer.class))
            return Integer.parseInt(str);
        else if (type.equals(Double.class))
            return Double.parseDouble(str);
        else if (type.equals(Boolean.class))
            return Boolean.parseBoolean(str);
        else return type.cast(str);
    }
```

It works enough, but I would like to make it work with mostly all cases without having to add many more else if statements. As well as this, I am required to cast to that type when I take the input and assign it to a variable. Is there a way I could get around this?

```
Invocation:
int num = (int)menu.getInput("Enter an integer: ", Integer.class);
```

Comment: Have dedicated methods for each input type (ie `getInt(...)`), personally, it's clearer.  Alternatively, you could devise a parser `interface` which you would pass it and it'd do the parsing itself

Comment: As you appear to know at the call site which type you want, and as there are a finite number of types, just write a method for each and remove an opportunity for error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to use reflection since these classes(`Integer`, `Boolean`...) usually have a static `valueOf` method:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int input = getInput("1", Integer.class);
        System.out.println(input);
    }

    public static <T> T getInput(String input, Class<T> type) {
        try {
            Method valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
            return type.cast(valueOf.invoke(null, input));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: String seems to not have a `valueOf()` method but I could just check if `type.equals(String.class)`.
I also am running a problem with this because `return type.cast(valueOf.invoke(null, input));` returns an Object when the method declaration is asking for type T. Is it just as simple as casting it with `(T)`?

Comment: What do you mean by ```returns an Object```.  Isn't it already returning a generic type?

Comment: Never mind. I accidentally left `Class<?>` in the method signature. It works fine now!
Quick question though, why when you use `type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);` do you specify `String.class`?

Comment: Because ```valueOf``` accepts a input parameter of type ```String```.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you "might" do this, but probably one of the ways which won't have you modifying the "base" input method every time you want a new input type, would be to inject the "parsing" workflow into the method itself.

That is, create a generic `interface` which defines a "parse" method which can take a `String` and return value of a specific type and pass that to your input method, for example...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public final class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        Integer result = getInput("Please enter an integer: ", new IntParser());
    }

    public interface Parsable<T> {
        public T parse(String value);
    }

    public class IntParser implements Parsable<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer parse(String value) {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    }

    public <T> T getInput(String prompt, Parsable<T> parser) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = scn.nextLine();

        return parser.parse(str);
    }
}
```

Now, if you didn't want to have to type `getInput("Please enter an integer: ", new IntParser());` every time , you could create connivence methods to make your life easier, for example...

```
public int getIntInput(String prompt) {
    return getInput(prompt, new IntParser());
}
```

Now, me, I'd probably create class to encompass it all...

```
public class InputManager {

    public interface Parsable<T> {
        public T parse(String value);
    }

    public class IntParser implements Parsable<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer parse(String value) {
            return Integer.parseInt(value);
        }
    }
    
    protected Scanner scanner;

    public InputManager(Scanner scanner) {
        this.scanner = scanner;
    }

    public InputManager() {
        this(new Scanner(System.in));
    }

    public <T> T getInput(String prompt, Parsable<T> parser) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        return parser.parse(str);
    }

    public int getIntInput(String prompt) {
        return getInput(prompt, new IntParser());
    }
}
```

But I am crazy

**Important** - This doesn't deal with error handling.  I might, for example, have the `Parsable` return `null` when it's unable to parse the result, otherwise you should probably define a `ParsingException` so that calls are made aware of their responsibilities